# How to hide all elements of class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this function:

```
document.getElementsByClassName = function(c){
    for(var i=0,a=[],o;o=document.body.getElementsByTagName('*')[i++];){
        if(RegExp('\\b'+c+'\\b','gi').test(o.className)){
            a.push(o);
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

How can I hide all elements by class?

I tried:

```
var array = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    $(array[i]).hide();
}
```

But I got error:

```
Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]
```

Comment: Seeing as you're using jQuery, why aren't you just doing `$('.classname').hide()`?

Comment: Because I must add event "click" for each element.

Comment: This seems like a lot of writing for something that could be done with `$(".hide").hide()` ?

Comment: Why do you want to add a click event to something that's being hidden?

Comment: Then just do `$(".hide").hide().on('click', function() { $(this).show(); });` etc ???

Comment: @Never You can still add a click event for each element using jQuery: `$('.classname').hide().click();`

Comment: I have two groups and I want to:

First element in X group: Add event: Hide first element in Y group.

Comment: All of that is possible with jQuery, take a look at the [API](http://api.jquery.com/), lots of useful stuff

Comment: `$(xgroup).hide().on('click', function() { $(ygroup).eq($(this).index()).hide(); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using vanilla JavaScript, then:

```
var array = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    array[i].style.display = 'none';
    array[i].onclick = function(){
        // do stuff
    };
    /* or:
    array[i].addEventListener('click',functionToCall);
    */
}
```

But, given that you're using jQuery, I don't understand why you're complicating things for yourself, just use:

```
$('.hide').hide();
```

Further to the above, given your comment:

> Because I must add event "click" for each element.

Simply use:

```
$(elementSelector).click(
    function(){
        // do stuff
    });
```

Assuming you want to hide, and bind a click-event to, the same elements:

```
$('.hide').hide().click(
    function(){
        // do stuff
    });
```

Comment: How can I use jQuery Hide with array[i] (from first example)?

Answer (score 4):

jQuery allows CSS selectors to be used, doing away with the need for hand-built loops and regular expressions. To hide an element with class `fooey`, just do

```
$('.fooey').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you get from `getElementsByClassName` is NOT an array, but a `NodeList`, hence the error when trying to loop.

However, you can still loop over a NodeList using the following:

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
for(var x in nodeList){}
```